# Multi categories posts

Tags: laravel-5

I'm using **laravel 5.6** and i have two tables categories and posts

I have created **`category_id`** in posts table which looks like

**`{id, category_id, title, description, created_at, updated_at}`**

I created a drop-down on the post create and edit form to select the category which works fine.

Now I am looking for something more advanced where a post can have multiple categories. I have changed **`belongTo`** to **`HasMany`** categories in post model.

I feel I am doing it the wrong way.  Do i need to create another table i.e.,
**`post_categories`**

**`{id, category_id, post_id}`**

The reason i want to do this is because i have multiple posts which belong to multiple categories and my route is like this

```
site.com/categoryname/post-slug
```

So few posts appear in multiple categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably will need to use the pivot table. That way you can data mine. Even if you don't have a multi-select, you'll easily be able to collect posts linked to categories and vice versa. [laraveldaily-good example](http://laraveldaily.com/pivot-tables-and-many-to-many-relationships/). They use the sync method, one of my favs. when you save the form data you can just do something like `App\Post::find($id)->categories()->sync(request()->input(categories'))` and laravel will handle the rest for you.

Your relationships look like they are thought out. to me, it looks like your on the right track.
Just use the **belongsToMany** relationship instead of HasMany

Laravel has great documentation on this: [laravel many to many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

Comment: That was clear. And the links you provided helps me understand this. Thank you